# How to pull points that are within a certain distance away in R?

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have a parameter space given by (x,y) with `x` values from `1:5` and `y` values from `1:8`. Let's say my current point `p` is located at `(2,5)` (it is colored in red). My goal is to try to pull all the points within one unit distance away from point `p` (the points in blue).
[image]

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to do this. Let's say my variables are stored in the following way:

```
xrange <- 1:5
yrange <- 1:8
grid <- expand.grid(xrange,yrange)
p <- data.frame(x=2,y=5)
```

I would like to store the other points below `p` in this fashion:

```
res <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),y=c(4,6,4,5,6,4,5,6))
res <- rbind(p,res)
> res
  x y
1 2 5
2 1 4
3 1 6
4 1 4
5 2 5
6 2 6
7 3 4
8 3 5
9 3 6
```

The ultimate goal is to have a parameter space that is more than 2 dimensional. So I would eventually like to find all points that are some euclidean distance `s` away and similarly have a resulting dataframe with each column being a parameter in the parameter space and each row being a point with coordinates `(x,y,z,..,etc)` from its columns.

**EDIT** I have tried the following implementation if I wanted a circle or euclidean distance `s` and this seems to work. I am not sure how efficient the solution is though.

```
eucdist <- function(z,p){

      return(dist(rbind(z, p)))
    }

# in this case s=1 since that is the <= condition
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(grid),function(m) if(eucdist(as.numeric(grid[m,]),as.numeric(p[1,])) <= 1){return(grid[m,])}))
```

More information: for now, my parameter space is discretized like the one in the picture above. Eventually some parameters will be continuous mixed in with discrete parameters as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The euclidean distance of each point on the grid from the target point `p` can be efficiently computed with:

```
dist <- sqrt(rowSums(mapply(function(x,y) (x-y)^2, grid, p)))
```

Basically the inner `mapply` call will result in a matrix of the same size as `grid` but that has the squared distance of that point from the target point in that dimension; `rowSums` and `sqrt` efficiently then compute the euclidean distance.

In this case you are including anything with `sqrt(2)` Euclidean distance from the target point:

```
grid[dist < 1.5,]
#    Var1 Var2
# 16    1    4
# 17    2    4
# 18    3    4
# 21    1    5
# 22    2    5
# 23    3    5
# 26    1    6
# 27    2    6
# 28    3    6
```

The use of `mapply` (operating over dimensions) and `rowSums` makes this much more efficient than an approach that loops through individual points on the grid, computing the distance to the target point. To see this, consider a slightly larger example with 1000 randomly distributed points in three dimensions:

```
set.seed(144)
grid <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000), z=rnorm(1000))
p <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1), y=rnorm(1), z=rnorm(1))
lim <- 1.5
byrow <- function(grid, p, lim) grid[apply(grid, 1, function(x) sqrt(sum((x-p)^2))) < lim,]
vectorized <- function(grid, p, lim) grid[sqrt(rowSums(mapply(function(x,y) (x-y)^2, grid, p))) < lim,]
identical(byrow(grid, p, lim), vectorized(grid, p, lim))
[1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
# Unit: microseconds
#                      expr       min         lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
#       byrow(grid, p, lim) 446792.71 473428.137 500680.0431 495824.7765 521185.093 579999.745    10
#  vectorized(grid, p, lim)    855.33    881.981    954.1773    907.3805   1081.658   1108.679    10
```

The vectorized approach is 500 times faster than the approach that loops through the rows.

This approach can be used in cases where you have many more points (1 million in this example):

```
set.seed(144)
grid <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000000), y=rnorm(1000000), z=rnorm(1000000))
p <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1), y=rnorm(1), z=rnorm(1))
lim <- 1.5
system.time(vectorized(grid, p, lim))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.466   0.136   3.632
```

Comment: ahhh i see. the way `mapply` works is such that your function `(x-y)^2` will simply take the distance between `grid` and `p` regardless of the number of dimensions?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom it loops through the columns one by one, computing the resulting vector for each.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with package `FNN`. The result is different from what you have because your solution has (1 4) and (2 5) twice. The solution also works with border data. You will only have 6 nearest neighbors if your x or y is 1 or on the edge of your matrix.

```
library(FNN)
x <-2
y <- 5
pt <-grid[grid$Var1==x & grid$Var2==y ,] #target point
distance <-knnx.dist(grid,pt,k=9) #distance from pt
k <-length(distance[distance<2]) #distance is less than 2. Useful for border data 
nearest <-knnx.index(grid,pt,k=k) #find index of k nearest neighbors

grid[nearest,]

   Var1 Var2
22    2    5
23    3    5
27    2    6
21    1    5
17    2    4
26    1    6
28    3    6
18    3    4
16    1    4
```

I see that you also have asked for higher dimensions. It would still work witht he following changes:

```
x <-2
y <- 5
z <-3
pt <-grid[grid$Var1==x & grid$Var2==y & grid$Var3==z ,] #3-dimensional point
distance <-knnx.dist(grid,pt,k=27) #increase to k=27
k <-length(distance[distance<2])
nearest <-knnx.index(grid,pt,k=k)
grid[nearest,]
```

Comment: @P Lapointe this is a nice solution but if dimensions were to grow large to an n-dimensional space then I will have to manually change the code to adapt the `k=` value which I am not sure I even understand

Comment: k is simply the number of nearest neighbors you want. With two dimensions, you want nine nearest neighbors. In your plot, these are the eight blue dots plus the red dot. The equation to get nine is 3^dimension so, 3^2=9. At dimension=3, 3^3=27. Picture this as a 3x3x3 cube with center piece being your point. At dimension 4, k= 3^4=81.